# Using a path variable with spaces in it on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, path, escaping

I can't quite figure out how to correctly set a path variable and utilize it when the path contains spaces. Tried looking it up but could only find solutions for Windows and not Linux.

I have the following variable:

```
rootDirectory = os.getcwd() # = "/home/happyb/Python/Python Tests"
```

And I'm using this variable to refer to the application's root folder. The root folder is named Python Tests. The whole path looks like this: "/home/happyb/Python/Python Tests"

I want to be able to use the rootDirectory variable in other paths, so for example:

```
file = open(f'{rootDirectory}/bin/Settings.txt'), "r")
```

But this always leads to a FileNotFoundError.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- raw strings (using r'PATHHERE'), but I think those only work on windows paths, right?
- replacing the whitepaces in the path with '\ '
- using the pathlib Path class (been using just Path)

I can't quite figure it out. I know I'm missing something, but I'm not quite sure what. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: why do you think this has to do with spaces in the path? Are you sure `'/home/happyb/Python/Python Tests//bin/Settings.txt'` exists?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, it exists. Accidentally put the ending / on the path. That's not correct, it's actually "/home/happyb/Python/Python Tests"

Comment: That should work though. You do not need escaping unless you are going through shell; open certainly doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

why don`t you try python third lib?Can auto-adapte path(linux、windows)

```
import os

file_path="a s "
result_path=os.path.join(file_path, "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it just works. Maybe it's a problem of different part?

Code (Tested in Linux and Windows):

```
dir = "~/test test"

#prints first line well
print(open(f'{dir}/test.txt', 'r').readline())
```